# .NET: DropDownList not showing up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

When I run this, the dropdownlist doesn't show up at all. It was showing up at an earlier point; I'm not sure what I changed to make it not work. Only the submit button shows up.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Enter Wellness Activity
    </h1>

    Select Activity Type:<br />
    @{
        List<Activity> acts = ViewBag.Activities;
        var selectItems = new SelectList(acts, "code", "shortTitle");
        ViewBag.selectItems = selectItems;
    }

    <div class="input">
        @{
            Html.BeginForm("ActivitySelected", "Home");
            Html.DropDownList("selectItems");
            <br />
           <button name="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button> 

           // Html.EndForm();
        }           
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make three changes to this code to get it to work. Change the DropDownList, change the Form, and change the submit button, like below:

```
<div class="input">
    @using(Html.BeginForm("ActivitySelected", "Home"))
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("selectItems", ViewBag.selectItems)
        <br />

       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
</div>
```

By the way, instead of assigning the SelectList to `ViewBag.selectItems` in your View, do it in your Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try Html.DropDownList("selectItems", selectItems);

See this overload method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548304(v=vs.111).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the items into the `ViewBag.selectItems` you are not doing anything with them.

Try passing them into the dropdown:

```
Html.DropDownList("selectItems", ViewBag.selectItems);
```